# cannot understand rails activerecord typecast reasons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

consider that i have a migration as follows

```
create_table :dummies do |t|
  t.decimal :the_dummy_number
end
```

i instantiate like the following

```
dummy = Dummy.new
dummy.the_dummy_number = "a string"
puts dummy.the_dummy_number
```

the output for the above is

```
 0.0
```

> how did this happen? since i assign a wrong value shouldn't it raise an error?

The biggest problem is the following.

Since it automatically converts my **validate** method fails miserably.

**update**-the validate method

```
 validate :is_dummy_number_valid, :the_dummy_number
 def is_dummy_number_valid
    read_attribute(:the_dummy_number).strip()
 end
```

Comment: What validation method are you using? if you use `validates_numericality_of :the_dummy_number` it should work fine

Comment: Your validation method doesn't do any validation!

Comment: was giving just an example..! probably i manipulate after stripping..!

Comment: One point to watch out for is that the return value of validation methods is ignored. If you define your own validation methods you have to manually add items to the errors array to create a validation failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that this does not work as you expect is that the underlying ruby implementation of BigDecimal does not error when passed a string.

Consider the following code

```
[ 'This is a string', '2is a string', '2.3 is also a string', 
  '   -3.3 is also a string'].each { |d| puts "#{d} = #{BigDecimal.new(d)}" }

This is a string = 0.0
2is a string = 2.0
2.3 is also a string = 2.3
   -3.3 is also a string = -3.3
```

So BigDecimal scans the string and assigns anything at the beginning of the string that could be a decimal to its value.

If you set your model up like this

```
class Dummy < ActiveRecord::Base

   validates_numericality_of :the_dummy_number

end
```

Then the validation should work fine

```
>> d=Dummy.new(:the_dummy_number => 'This is a string')
=> #<Dummy id: nil, the_dummy_number: #<BigDecimal:5b9230,'0.0',4(4)>, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

>> puts d.the_dummy_number
0.0
=> nil
>> d.valid?
=> false

>> d.errors
=> #<ActiveRecord::Errors:0x5af6b8 @errors=#<OrderedHash
  {"the_dummy_number"=>[#<ActiveRecord::Error:0x5ae114 
   @message=:not_a_number, @options={:value=>"This is a string"}
```

This works because the validates_numericality_of macro uses the raw_value method to get at the value before it was typecast and assigned to the internal decimal value.